# makefile: no such file or dir

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am having problem with my makefile. This makefile is given, so I should be able to use it. But somehow I am having "No such file or directory" error with LDFLAGS tag.

All files are in the same directory with the makefile.

Here is the screenshots of the makefile and the compiler:
[image: makefile]
[image: compiler]

I have tried changing LDFLAGS to ./..., *.out but none worked. I could not understand what is the problem and also what `LDFLAGS = ...` means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after changing `LDFLAGS` from `...` to and empty tag.